# TypeScript exclude external directory from compilation

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, directory-structure, tsconfig

I have the following folder structure for my microservices:

- service1

  - tsconfig.json
  - src/...
  - dist/...
- service2

  - Same as service1
- shared

  - tsconfig.json
  - src/...

I want to include files from "shared" into my services.
But the idea is that the files from shared don't get compiled or copied into the service (this is done by a docker volume later). I only need the reference and types from the shared file.

This is the tsconfig.json from the services

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": ["../shared/src/*"]
    },
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    ...    
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "../shared/**",
    "@shared/**",
    ...
  ]
}
```

I've also tried to do just "../shared" and "@shared" without success.

And this is a example service:

```js
import RMQ from "@shared/util/rabbitmq";
// Do something here with RMQ

RMQ.sub(someQueue, someListener);
```

With this I get the following error on compilation:
*error TS6059: File '/shared/src/util/rabbitmq.ts' is not under 'rootDir'
'/service1/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.*

When I remove the rootDir from the config in service1 it works, but the folder structure looks like this then:

- dist

  - src/index.js
  - shared/util/rabbitmq.js

How can I explizitly exclude the files from the "shared" folder in my services from compilation?

Notice that the shared folder also contains implementations, so just changing it to .d.ts won't help.